# C++ Qt WordCount and large data sets

Tags: c++, qt, word-count

I want to count words occurrences in a set of plain text files. Just like here http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtconcurrent-wordcount-main-cpp.html

The problem is that i need to process very big amount of plain text files - so my result srored in QMap could not fit into memory.

I googled external memory (file based) merge sort algorithm, but i'm too lazy to implement myself. So i want to divide result set by portions to fit each of them into memory. Then store this portions in files on disk. Then call magic function mergeSort(QList, result_file) and have final result in result_file.

Does anyone know Qt compatible implementation of this algo?

In short i'm looking for pythons heapq.merge (http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) analog but for Qt containers.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check out this one:
http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/

It's not exactly what you are looking for (close enough though), but I guess you will not find exactly what you want working with Qt lists. Since you are are implementing alghoritm creating this list, changing it's type shouldn't be a problem. As far as i remember on those list you can use standard stl sorting alghoritms. The only problem remains preformance.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the map contains the association between the word and the number of occurences. In this case, why do you say you have such a significant memory consumption? How many distinct words and forms could you have and what is the average memory consumption for one word?

Considering 1.000.000 words, with 1K memory consumption per word (that includes the word text, the QMap specific storage), that would lead to (aprox) 1GB of memory, which... doesn't seem so much to me.